# CircleCI using absolute path, not relative

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-automation, circleci

I am building an Android Application using CircleCI, and within the project I compile an Android Library as a dependency. However, I get the following error during the CircleCI build:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':aModule'.
> The SDK directory '/home/myname/Android/Sdk' does not exist.
```

It looks like CircleCI is attempting to use some build tools to compile the module, but fails because it is using an absolute path on my machine. How would I configure CircleCI to use a local path of the Android SDK, if possible?

Here is my `build.gradle` as well, if necessary:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.glomadrian:roadrunner:1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile project(':aModule')
}
```

* Update: The SDK path is set in my project's local.properties

Comment: delete local.properties from repo perhaps, for me there was not one uploaded... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32149274/1815624

Comment: hope this may help https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/b0367cc5e54774cf4ce5366ceb127732

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was to use the following in a `circle.yml` file

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
    artifacts:
        - /home/ubuntu/your-app-name/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
  environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
    GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8

checkout:
  post:
    - git submodule sync
    - git submodule update --init

dependencies:
    pre:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-25.0.2,android-25,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support
        - chmod +x gradlew
        - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies

test:
    override:
        - (./gradlew assemble):
            timeout: 360
```

permission for gradlew and setting ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux seemed to be what was needed...

but I have been using circleci for about 30 minutes...