# Android Studio:SDK directory does not exists

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am trying to open an android studio project, but I keep getting the message:

"The SDK directory 'D:\AndroidSDK' does not exist.
Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file."

I already checked the SDK home path in the module setting and it is the same as that in local.properties.
I hope someone can help me with the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidStudio SDK directory does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149220/androidstudio-sdk-directory-does-not-exists)

Comment: possible duplicate of , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149220/androidstudio-sdk-directory-does-not-exists

Comment: I tried the solution proposed in that post but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

After updating the SDK path try to clean Android Studio's cache e make a refresh restart, you can use:

> On the main menu, choose **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**. The
>   Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will
>   be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the
>   dialog to invalidate caches, restart IntelliJ IDEA or both.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html