# Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file. Studio removed slashes in path. Import project error. How to solve, debug?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

I am trying to import a project. It gives an error for local.properties 
`Please fix the 'sdk.dir' property in the local.properties file.`

Found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149220/androidstudio-sdk-directory-does-not-exists), but no solutions worked.

Error is:

`The SDK directory C:\MyProject\C:AndroidSdk does not exists`

I edit local.properties and set `sdk.dir=C\:\\AndroidSdk` and hit Try again, but it is showing the same error and also removed slashes and saved `C:AndroidSdk` as property value in newly generated `local.properties.`

I am Working on windows, Android Studio version : 3.3.1

Comment: Make sure ,android sdk folder is present in c: drive.

Comment: Yes it is present C:\AndroidSdk

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596284/sdk-location-not-found-in-android-studio

Comment: Project Defaults also points same directory as above C:\AndroidSdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find what actual problem was. But upgrading Android Studio to 3.4 solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you import or try to open a dev to dev project, Android Studio try to sync the project SDK, showing a message informing a SDK error. Do not click on the OK button.

Just close the message and try to execute the project.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! Here, all the questions and answers need to be in english. If you want, you can use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ , which is all in portuguese.

Comment: @Donizete Gomes , what you want to say by "dev to dev project"?

Comment: @alxlives , answer is now in english, you should remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If i delete the local.properties and rerun the build all works.

File --> Invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the project, try to open it as an existing project, then you will get a prompt from the android studio that it didn't find the default path so it chose one specific to your computer